# Unresolved reference, when trying to import an app in django

Tags: python, django

I'm having problems while trying to import my app.(unresolved reference of new_app and some_page)

[image]

views.py content:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse


def some_page(request):
    return HttpResponse('Hello world')
```

In settings i've added app:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'new_app'
]
```

Comment: You should mark the outermost `Practice` as source root directory...

Answer (score 0):

Simply change your import to:

```
from Practice.new_app import some_page
```

And make sure to include an `__init__.py` file in the Practice directory too.

The `__init__.py` file can be blank in this use case.